# Are there any alternate module for qq_import module (Quiz Questions Import Module)?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting, quiz

Are there any alternate module for [qq_import module](http://drupal.org/project/qq_import) (Quiz Questions Import Module) ? It seems it has no Drupal 7 version for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns our that there are some similar existing modules on D7 but not as close as qq_import module. Instead, I just created my own custom D7 quiz question importer. It only imports multiple choice type of questions though

Comment: I did the same. May be we should join hands to create a module at leaset for the multiple choice questions.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too.

I want to import my multiple choice questions from one D7 to another D7 website but there is no easy way of doing it. I have tried the Node Export module but it does not import the Multiple Choice questions with the answer choices, only the question stem is imported.

It seems like you have written your own custom module. Do you think it would help to try your module on my D7 site as well? If so, could you share some more information.

Thanks